# При создании триггера ошибка: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT"

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

У меня имеется таблица `crafts(id_craft,name_craft)`, в которой каждое ремесло имеет уникальный номер. Чтобы не задавать его вручную я использую триггер:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_craft
  BEFORE INSERT ON crafts
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT craft_sqn.NEXTVAL
    INTO :new.id_craft
    FROM dual;
END;
```

А затем я пишу какое-нибудь выражение, например:

```
INSERT INTO crafts
(name_craft)
VALUES('Ловля рыбы');
```

и появляется ошибка

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT"

Правильно ли я понимаю, что этот запрос воспринимается как продолжение триггера?   И что нужно сделать, чтобы исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прежде всего, начиная с 11g можно присваивать следующее значение последовательности напрямую в переменную, то есть без запроса:

```
create or replace trigger trig_craft
    before insert on crafts for each row
begin
    :new.id_craft := craft_sqn.nextval;
end;
```

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что этот запрос воспринимается как продолжение триггера?

Да, правильно. Последняя `;` являются частью синтаксиса PL/SQL. Клиент, который посылает выражение `CREATE`, должен знать, где оно заканчивается. В большинстве консольных клиентов для этого служит `/` (только один слэш в новой строке) -
*закончить запись в буфер и послать его на выполнение*.

В клиентах с графическим интерфейсом достаточно выделить полное выражение и нажать комбинацию клавиш - «Выполнить». Посмотрите, недействительное выражение `xxxxxx` никак не мешает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Trigger TRIG_CRAFT compiled

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_craft
  BEFORE INSERT ON crafts
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT craft_sqn.NEXTVAL
    INTO :new.id_craft
    FROM dual;
END;
/
```